# Bind an IOrderedEnumerable<> to wpf Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, caliburn.micro

I currently have a datagrid that has a list of Items bound to it using caliburn micro.

```
       <DataGrid x:Name="Items" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Warehouse.Label}"Header="Label"/>                                    
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Warehouse.Count}"Header="Count"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Article}"Header="Article"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Otherinfo}"Header="Other info"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This list contains a property warehouse. To make this cleaner i want to order this list by warehouse.

this can be done easily in linq, but once the list is ordered it changes to a IOrderedEnumerable<>.

is there a way to order this with linq where i populate the list? Or any way to do this in the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataGrid columns sorting feature or link a ListCollectionView initialized with your collection with Sort function

Comment: will look into this, it's my first time making something in wpf that's why i defaulted to linq because it's something that i know more of